# How to change PHP version on WAMP and dynamically change it also on Environment Variables?

Tags: php, wamp

Currently, I am working with PHP 7.4.26 and PHP 8.1.0, I can easily change my PHP version on my WAMP but I cannot do it on Environment Variables without changing it manually and restarting the computer.
Is there any way to change my WAMP PHP version and also dynamically change the PHP version on Environment Variables?
Images will follow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance!